# nginx redirection loop with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to deny access to some ressources unless they are known IPs.

I've came up with this, it seems good on the paper, but when running it I've got an endless redirection loop:

```
    location ~ ^/(?!(not-ready-yet|robots\.txt)).*$ {
        error_page 403 = @badip;
        allow 172.22.0.8;
        deny all;

        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location @badip {
        return 301 $scheme://$http_host/not-ready-yet;
    }
```

I dont't understand why, shouldn't I be redirected once and then match the second location ?

This is a temporary restriction, so an ugly hack is totally acceptable as it won't stay in the codebase.

Comment: Your regex matches `/index.php` too, so I guess that's why you loop. I assume you want to permit access to the not-yet-ready and robots.php pages only from a single IP, so you wouldn't need to use a negative lookahead, just an alternation of the two : `^/(not-ready-yet|robots\.txt)`

Comment: I want to deny access to all ressources except not-ready-yet and robots for non whitelisted ips. I didn't though that try_files directive were evaluated by locations blocks. I had the assumption that only a return or rewrite would trigger other locations block. I'll try adding index.php to my negative lookahead tomorrow to see if it do the trick

Comment: @Aaron, you we're right adding index.php to the negative lookahead prevent looping.
If you wan't to turn your comment into an answer, I can accept it.